# Formula to search for a matching item on two Google sheets and then fill in a third value if a match is found

Tags: google-sheets

I have two google sheets.

-Sales Sheet 
-Goal sheet

**On the sales sheet:**

Column I has a list of items
Column J is blank

**On the goal sheet:**

Column A has a list of items 
Column I has a list of values.

I need a formula to enter on the Sales sheet, which will search for the item listed in column I for a matching item on column A of the goal sheet.

When a match is found, it needs to take the value found in column I of the goal sheet and place it into column J of the sales sheet.

I've tried several formulas using MATCH but I just can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be sincerely and greatly appreciated!!

I tired this formula, but it seems to be filling in the value from column A instead of the corresponding value from column I. I know I'm missing a step here, but I don't know where to start:

=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("[Sheet ID]","Page!I1:I500"),MATCH(A121,A1:A500,0))

Comment: show us what you tried!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

=INDEX(IMPORTRANGE("[sheet ID]","Goal-sheet!$I$2:$I$500"),MATCH(I5,IMPORTRANGE("[sheet ID]","Goal-Guide-Internal!$A$2:$A$500"),0))